# Any recommendations for a good PHP script running framework? Queue based trigger for the scripts

Tags: php, frameworks, queue

I'm looking for a good framework to run PHP back-end business logic in combination with a queue service. the framework needs to be able to maintain large number of php processes up and running waiting for queue events.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As for the framework you can use any of the good frameworks out there and I'm not going into the framework debate, so let's just see what would be practical in terms of queue handling:

- Zend Framework has [Zend_Queue](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.queue.html) which gives you adapters for Apache ActiveMQ, Database, Memcache, Zend Server and array (for testing). That's a pretty good out of the box feature set and you can extend it to wrap any other queue management tool.
- This blog post talks about [implementing beanstalkd with the Symfony2](http://dahlstroem.dk/2011/04/using-beanstalkd-with-the-symfony-2-di-container/) framework
- [Wrapping a linux](https://github.com/treffynnon/PHP-at-Job-Queue-Wrapper) tool is another option

So there are tons of options, the only concrete advice I would give is [not to make the mistake of implementing the queue system with a relational database](http://www.engineyard.com/blog/2011/5-subtle-ways-youre-using-mysql-as-a-queue-and-why-itll-bite-you/).

If this doesn't answer your question I guess you have to give us more details about your requirements.